# Maximizing over a p-Frobenius norm ball

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces

Let $p\in [1,\infty]$, $p^*$ be s.t. $1/p+1/p^* =1$ (when $p=1$, $p^*$ is understood to be $\infty$, and vice versa). $||u||_p :=(\sum_{i=1}^n |u_i|^p)^{1/p}$ is the p-norm for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $||U||_{F,p}:=(\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n |U_{ij}|^p)^{1/p}$ is the p-Frobenius norm for $m \times n$ matrices. 
I'd like to show
$$\max_{\Delta:||\Delta||_{F,p}\leq \lambda}||y-(X+\Delta)\beta||_p=||y-X\beta||_p +\lambda ||\beta||_{p*}$$
I realize I'm even having trouble showing "$\leq$": By the triangle ineq, $||y-(X+\Delta)\beta||_p$ $\leq||y-X\beta||_p +||\Delta \beta||_p$.  So the issue is why $||\Delta||_{F,p}\leq \lambda$ implies $||\Delta \beta||_p \leq \lambda ||\beta||_{p*}$. I know this result for p=2 (since the Frobenius norm is an upper bound on the operator norm, by considering the singular values), but working w/ the p-Frobenius norm is new to me. 
I have started by using $||\Delta \beta||_p =\max_{u:||u||_p* \leq 1} u^T \Delta \beta$, which seems promising but I still get stuck.
Even though I'm stuck showing "$\leq$" I still need to show "$\geq$", so I'd also appreciate some help w/ that.